# react-native props updated and render called, but UI doesn't updated

Tags: react-native, react-redux, native-base

I have a react-native component that uses native-base.

I also integrated react-redux and have connected properly, thus my state automatically updated by the reducer.

My problem is, my `props.data` gets updated properly and `render` gets called, but my `ListItem` is not updated at all.. I am not very familiar with this react-native components, did I miss anything?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
  ListItem,
  List
} from "native-base";

import {
  Provider,
  connect
} from 'react-redux';

class MyPage extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    console.log('data: ' + JSON.stringify(data)); // this gets called 
     2x, 1st time is empty, 2nd time is filled
    // 2nd times it gets called, looked something like this: "data: 
     [{"name": "one"},{"name": "two"}]"
    return (
        <irrelevant components omitted>
        <List
         dataArray={data}
         renderRow={row =>
          <ListItem
            button
            onPress={() => {console.log("todo: navigation")}}>
            <Text>{row.name}</Text>
          </ListItem>
        }
      />
       <irrelevant components omitted>
    );
  }
}
```

But, the UI still renders empty even after the second call... any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the list render when you use an array defined in the component?

Comment: yes, it renders with hardcoded data

Comment: try with FlatList instead of List.